# Teamcity - Revisions are not found for build configurations

Tags: build, teamcity, snapshot

I have two build configurations: A and B. A is fetching the sources from a Git repository, building the source code and running unit and integration tests, B should deploy the application to a test environment. B has a "Finish Build Trigger" and a "Snapshot Dependency" on A. A is successfully running and I'm  expecting that B will start after A, but I get the following error:

> Revisions are not found for build configurations: A {id=bt7}, B
>   {id=bt9}   Hide stacktrace 
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.BuildTriggerException: Revisions
>   are not found for build configurations: A {id=bt7}, B {id=bt9}   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTriggersChecker.callTrigger(BuildTriggersChecker.java:37)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTriggersChecker.access$800(BuildTriggersChecker.java:109)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTriggersChecker$BuildTriggersGroup.processTriggers(BuildTriggersChecker.java:27)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTriggersChecker.triggerBuilds(BuildTriggersChecker.java:94)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildServerRunner$4.doSomething(BuildServerRunner.java:1)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildServerRunner$BuildServerWorker.runAction(BuildServerRunner.java:12)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildServerRunner$BuildServerWorker.run(BuildServerRunner.java:32)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)   Caused by:
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.RevisionsNotFoundException: Revisions
>   are not found for build configurations: A {id=bt7}, B {id=bt9}   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.HistoryChangesCollector$HistoryChangesResult.checkRevisionsAreSet(HistoryChangesCollector.java:30)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.HistoryChangesCollector$HistoryChangesResult.computeRevisions(HistoryChangesCollector.java:27)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.HistoryChangesCollector$HistoryChangesResult.access$100(HistoryChangesCollector.java:74)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.HistoryChangesCollector$1.get(HistoryChangesCollector.java:11)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.HistoryChangesCollector$1.get(HistoryChangesCollector.java:3)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.CancelableTaskHolder.waitForTaskToComplete(CancelableTaskHolder.java:9)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.dependency.TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.doCollectChanges(TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.java:138)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.dependency.TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.access$000(TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.java:88)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.dependency.TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl$3.run(TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.java)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.dependency.TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl$3.run(TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.java:1)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.dependency.TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl$4.run(TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.java)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.SecurityContextImpl.runAs(SecurityContextImpl.java:24)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.SecurityContextImpl.runAsSystem(SecurityContextImpl.java:19)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.dependency.TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.runAsSystem(TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.java:122)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.dependency.TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.collectChangesForGraph(TopBuildDependencyGraphImpl.java:8)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildCustomizerImpl.createPromotion(BuildCustomizerImpl.java:53)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildCustomizerImpl.createPromotion(BuildCustomizerImpl.java:25)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.dependency.FinishBuildTriggerService$3.triggerBuild(FinishBuildTriggerService.java:48)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTriggersChecker.callTrigger(BuildTriggersChecker.java:50)

Comment: If  youve built the artifact in build A, wouldnt it be better to use as a build artifact/dependency in build b?

Comment: Do you know the answer? I have the same issue. I need to start 2 jobs  in parallel just after parent job finished and one of these job has no  VCS. Then there is exception

Answer (score 0):

How this `B` is configured?  How this `B` should have this artifact? Is it passed from `A` or `B` will build a it by itself and then deploy?

It seems that it does not have any VCS attached, does it? YOu can only have a snapshot dependency between two build configurations with the same VCS attached. TC will look after to make sure both builds are run against same revision. But in case one of the builds does not have VCS attached at all I will probably fail.